# How to add an int array Default Value for a FluentNHibernate mapping

Tags: c#, mysql, arrays, fluent-nhibernate, hibernate-mapping

Recently, I added a new column to my UserMap class, to add an int array

```
public class UserMap : ClassMap<User>
{
    public UserMap()
    {
        Table("user");
        LazyLoad();
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity().Column("Id");
        Map(x => x.DateCreated).Column("DateCreated").Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.Birthday).Column("Birthday").Nullable();
        Map(x => x.HideBirthday).Column("HideBirthday").Nullable();
        Map(x => x.Name).Column("Name").Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.Email).Column("Email").Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.PassWord).Column("Password").Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.NotificationCounter).Column("NotificationCounter").Nullable().Default("0");
        //EMAILPRIVACY = int[]
        Map(x => x.EmailPrivacy).Column("EmailPrivacy").Nullable();
    }
}
```

So, I need to add a Default Value to **EmailPrivacy** column with an int array.

```
new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 }
```

When I add the default value I got an error:

```
Map(x => x.EmailPrivacy).Column("EmailPrivacy").Nullable().Default(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 }.ToString());
```

Error message:

```
Unknown column 'user0_.EmailPrivacy' in 'field list'

[MySqlException (0x80004005): Unknown column 'user0_.EmailPrivacy' in 'field list']
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket() +383
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32& affectedRow, Int32& insertedId) +116
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.GetResult(Int32 statementId, Int32& affectedRows, Int32& insertedId) +54
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean force) +142
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult() +1249
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +2214
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +41
System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader() +12
NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher.ExecuteReader(IDbCommand cmd) +347
NHibernate.Loader.Loader.GetResultSet(IDbCommand st, Boolean autoDiscoverTypes, Boolean callable, RowSelection selection, ISessionImplementor session) +364
NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQuery(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies) +425
NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies) +213
NHibernate.Loader.Loader.LoadEntity(ISessionImplementor session, Object id, IType identifierType, Object optionalObject, String optionalEntityName, Object optionalIdentifier, IEntityPersister persister) +386
```

How can I add this int[] default value?

Thank you in advance to all

Comment: that error is coming from the database tho. Have you added a column `EmailPrivacy` in your database?

Comment: No, because the FluentNHibernate generates columns automatically when I add new elements

Comment: just add schemaupdate:
    return Fluently.Configure()
                .Database(databaseConfig)
                .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(pAssembly))
                .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => new SchemaUpdate(cfg).Execute(false,true))
                .BuildSessionFactory();

Comment: that must not be generating the column, but even if it was how does nhibernate know how to map an `int[]` to a single column ? interestingly, what happens if you manually add that column and run it?

Comment: Works fine, the error occurs just when I add the default value, as the question!